# Reducing object to simple array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have object of

```
{
0: "United States",
1: "India",
2: "Germany",
3: "Brazil",
4: "Taiwan",
5: "Israel",
6: "United Kingdom"
}
```

I just want to make it like using `jQuery` or `Javascript` only

```
["United States", "India", "Germany".....]
```

I already tried some codes like

> .reduce(), .flat(), or .concat()

but still not working

Comment: That looks like an object with square brackets, not an array

Comment: which kind of array do you have? I don't understand. What you wrote is not an array.

Comment: An array doesn't have a key. Are you sure it isn't an Object?

Comment: If it's a typo, and the above is an object and not an array like specified, then you can use `Object.values`.

Comment: Sorry I updated my question. It's an object and I need to make it into simple array

Comment: `let newArray = Object.values(myObject)`

Comment: @MarkSalvania use `Object.values()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

```
var obj= {
  0: "United States",
1: "India",
2: "Germany",
3: "Brazil",
4: "Taiwan",
5: "Israel",
6: "United Kingdom"
}

var result = Object.values(obj)

console.log(result);
```

**Solution 2**

```
var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return obj[key];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can remove the `map` with `let result = Object.values(obj)`

Answer (score 1):

You could assign the object to an array. This approach respects the keys.

```js
var object = { 0: "United States", 1: "India", 2: "Germany", 3: "Brazil", 4: "Taiwan", 5: "Israel", 6: "United Kingdom" },
    array = Object.assign([], object);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.map({0:"united states", 1: "India"}, function(q,w){return(w)})
> ["united states", "India"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const object = {
    0: 'United States',
    1: 'India',
    2: 'Germany',
    3: 'Brazil',
    4: 'Taiwan',
    5: 'Israel',
    6: 'United Kingdom'
  };

  const countries = Object.values(object);
```

Countries will contain your desired list